# How can I call a javascript function in a module from HTML when the module has been bundled by webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

This is probably a basic question but for some reason Google won't give me the answer.

I have a file called dropzone.stub.js in my src/ folder

```
import { Dropzone } from "dropzone";
Dropzone.autoDiscover = true;

// Callback takes one argument and that is the file that was 
// added.
export default function createDropZone(selector, url, callback) {
  const myDropzone = new Dropzone(selector, { url: url });
  myDropzone.on("addedfile", callback);
}
```

Basically I am just trying to call it from with script tags within my HTML file.

My webpack bundler is configured as follows:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/dropzone.stub.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'dropzone.bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
      //      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', {targets: 'defaults'}]
          }
        }
      },
//      {
//        test: /\.css$/i,
//        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
//      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
    // resolve: {
    //  extensions: [ '.js', '.jsx', '.css' ],
    //}
  },
};
```

The script section in my HTML browser at the moment just looks like this:

```
<script type="module">
  import { createDropZone } from '/static/dist/dropzone.bundle.js';

</script>
```

The browser reports the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/static/dist/dropzone.bundle.js' does not provide an export named 'createDropZone'
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: You’re exporting the function as the default but are importing a named function. Try removing the curly braces in the import statement?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Ok, I tried that but got a different error.  See proposed answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to import a webpack transpiled module from outside of webpack's scope which doesn't work. You really only have 2 options that I'm aware of. You can move your import statement from the html file to a javascript file such as `app.js` or something and run everything through webpack, or you would need to use babel along with webpack. I'd prefer the former but if that's not an option then maybe this will help point you in the right direction https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/

Comment: When I remove the braces I get the following error:  Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/static/dist/dropzone.bundle.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Comment: Post the code from dropzone.bundle.js

Comment: It's pretty big so I put it on https://pastebin.com/0d4v56EB

Comment: answer updated.

Comment: In the example in my OP I showed my webpack configuration which mentions babel-loader.  What else do I need to change?  Do I need something as a preset?

Answer (score -1):

What does the  bundled file look like. Webpack is most likely not bundling it as a es module.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0d4v56EB